# Formatting C++ setw

Tags: c++, format

I am working on formatting and I am not getting the correct formatting.

Here is my code and here is what I am getting for the output

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(3) << right << source << setw(20)
                 <<right <<vec[source].cityname
                 << setw(15) << left<< sink << setw(15) << left <<vec[sink].cityname
                 << setw(10) << left << vdist[ij] << "miles\n";
```

I am getting this:

```
30      Novosibirsk_RU13             Tokyo_JP       10497.68  miles
```

And I would like to be getting this:

```
30 Novosibirsk_RU       13  Tokyo_JP             10497.67 miles
```

How can I get that space between the name and the number?

I've been working on this for a while but I just can't get the right formatting

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `std::right` IO manipulator wrongly in your `cout` statement. To achieve the output as shown in your sample you want `vec[source].cityname` and `vec[sink].cityname` obviously left aligned:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(3) << right << source << 
                 setw(20) << left <<vec[source].cityname <<
                          // ^^^^
                 setw(3) << left<< sink << 
                   // ^
                 setw(15) << left <<vec[sink].cityname << 
                 setw(10) << left << vdist[ij] << "miles\n";
```

Also note, if you use `setw(n)` and `n` is smaller than the length of the next field (`string`) variable, it won't be cutoff, but shifts the whole output to the right for the number of additional characters.